# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Can any one help me, I am new to the iOS development what I am doing wrong in my code. When ever I tap the row it should insert another row below that.

Here is my code

**Error:** `reason:  'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3)`

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
    [self setupViewController];
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self)
{
    [self setupViewController];
}
return self;
}



- (void)setupViewController
{
NSArray* colors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"PENDENTS",@"EARRINGS",@"PENDENT SETS", nil];

self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0 ; i < [colors count] ; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray* section = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int j = 0 ; j < 1 ; j++)
    {
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EAR RINGS  ", j]];
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PENDENT SETS ",j]];
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PENDENTS ",j]];
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"25 pieces ",j]];
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"329.672 ",j]];
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"may 1 ",j]];
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"may 10 ",j]];
        [section addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"8,40,000 ",j]];
    }

    [self.data addObject:section];
}

self.headers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0 ; i < [colors count] ; i++)
{

    UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 40)];
    UILabel *lblpend=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 170, 40)];
    UILabel *lbldeliver=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(332, 0,113,40)];
    UILabel *lbltotal =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(562, 0, 200, 40)];

    [lblpend setText:@"RM-15/16-GRT-0102-CHE"];
    [lbldeliver setText:@"Delivered:27 Mar"];
    [lbltotal setText:@"941.92gms  Rs24,00,000"];

    [lbltotal setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    [lbldeliver setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    [lblpend setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

    [header addSubview:lblpend];
    [header addSubview:lbldeliver];
    [header addSubview:lbltotal];
    [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.headers addObject:header];
}
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.expandablecells=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cozycoracle",@"pendents",@"pendent sets", nil];

isTapped=YES;

[self.tbldata reloadData];
[self.tbldata openSection:0 animated:NO];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

## pragma tableview delegates

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (isTapped==YES) {

    isTapped=NO;

    return [self.expandablecells count];
}
return [self.data count];


}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
if (isTapped==YES) {

    isTapped=NO;

    return [self.expandablecells count];

}

return [self.data count];


}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cell";

MyOrderCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[MyOrderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}


if (isTapped==NO) {

    //isTapped=YES;

    NSString* text = [[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lblpendnts.text = text;
    cell.lblpieces.text=text;
    cell.lblnum.text=text;
    cell.lbldate.text=text;
    cell.lblenddate.text=text;
    cell.lbltotl.text=text;



}else{

    cell.lblpendnts.text = [self.expandablecells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblpieces.text=[self.expandablecells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblnum.text=[self.expandablecells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbldate.text=[self.expandablecells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblenddate.text=[self.expandablecells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbltotl.text=[self.expandablecells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}


return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

MyOrderCell *cell=[[MyOrderCell alloc]init];

if (isTapped==NO) {

    //isTapped=NO;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 & indexPath.row==0) {
        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        indexPath = newPath;

        [[self tbldata] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];


    }

}

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 50;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.headers objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Comment: You have always to keep the data source array and the UI in sync. `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` does only update the UI, before you call the method you have to insert the corresponding items at the same indexes in the data source array.

Answer (score 1):

your have this issue because you need to change datasource (add an object for new row) when calling

```
[[self tbldata] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

See details in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW20)

Answer (score 0):

i have updated like dis

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (isTapped==NO) {

    //isTapped=NO;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 & indexPath.row==0) {


        section=indexPath.section;
        numOfRows=indexPath.row;

        NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:[self.data count]];
        [self.tbldata beginUpdates];


        [self.tbldata insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
        [self.tbldata endUpdates];



    }
}

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

-(NSArray*) indexPathsForSection:(NSInteger)section withNumberOfRows:(NSInteger)numberOfRows
{
NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
    [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
}
return indexPaths;
}
```

Comment: i wil try it and check it bro

Comment: Also add this two line [tableview beginUpdates]; &  [tableview endUpdates]; before and after insert rows.

Comment: reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3),

Comment: Have you added above two lines?

Comment: count number of rows for your section before inserting rows.

Comment: NSInteger numOfRows;
        
        numOfRows= [[[arrayProductServiceList objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:section]] count];

Comment: in my section 3 rows are there before inserting.then after taps a row i have add another row ,for that i have taken another array and inserted the objects

Comment: So what you are getting in numberOfRowsForSection after insertrows. Please check.

Comment: Debug that scenario.

Comment: it crashes on tablview endupdats so that the numberOfRowsForSection method is not calling

Comment: So numberOfRows should be same when you collapse and expand your section. If you are adding new when it collapsed then you have to reload your table.

Comment: First update your data source so numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath will return the correct values for your post-insert data. You must do this before you insert or delete rows or you will see the "invalid number of rows" error that you're getting.

Then insert your rows.

Comment: Why you are adding this line MyOrderCell *cell=[[MyOrderCell alloc]init]; in didSelect method.

Comment: Remove this line if it's not useful. You are allocation new cell here.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I have added one function which returns indexpath array for your selected section with numberof rows.

Comment: if (isTapped==NO) {    
        if (indexPath.section == 0 & indexPath.row==0) {
            section=indexPath.section;
            numOfRows=indexPath.row;
            NSArray* indexPaths = [self indexPathsForSection:section withNumberOfRows:[self.data count]];
            [self.tbldata beginUpdates];            
            
            [self.tbldata insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
  [self.tbldata endUpdates];
  [self.tbldata reloadData];
           }

Comment: remove table reload.

Comment: What you get in NSArray * indexPaths?

Comment: what is your count in [self.data count]?

Comment: in nsaray indexpath i got like dis, indexpath (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}"

Comment: [self.data count] is 3 without insertion ..with insertion it crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115936/discussion-between-bhadresh-mulsaniya-and-vshnu).

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya `begin/endUpdates` has no effect at all in this case.

Comment: @vadian can you tell me why?

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya Because it's only required for **multiple** simultaneous `insert/delete/move` operations or **one** operation in a repeat loop, however the latter only for performance reasons.